# Selenium/Java - Writing Data to Excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to write a code to write data into excel. This code is working. However, it just write on the second row. When I change the value of "String FieldName1 to 3" it doesn't write on the next row. I change the value of header = spreadsheet.createRow(0); to (1) it did write to next row, but it is a pain to do it every time I run my test. What I need is to write the data to the next ROW everytime I run it and change the value of "String FieldName1 to 3". THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Selenium > Java > Maven

public class testBed2 {

```
@Test   
public void writeExcel() throws IOException{
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ExportExcel.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet( "TestData");
XSSFRow header;
header = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
header.createCell(0).setCellValue("FieldName1");
header.createCell(1).setCellValue("FieldName2");
header.createCell(2).setCellValue("FieldName3");
int rowNumber = 1;
            Row row = spreadsheet.getRow(0);

            //Column Count
            int colCount = row.getLastCellNum();
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
                System.out.println("Col Count : " + j);

            //Row Count
            int rowCount = spreadsheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; 
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

                XSSFRow currentRow = spreadsheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                System.out.println("Row Count : " + i);

                String FieldName1 = "NAME1";
                String FieldName2 = "NAME2";
                String FieldName3 = "NAME3";

                currentRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(FieldName1);
                currentRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(FieldName2);  
                currentRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(FieldName3);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\ExportExcel.xlsx");
                workbook.write(fos);
                fos.close();



        }

    }
```

}
}

Comment: You need to spend some time learning how to debug your own code or you will forever being asking others to help debug things for you. Look at the docs for the IDE you use on how to add a breakpoint and read some guides on debugging. it will save you a LOT of time in the future once you get even the basics of debugging down.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why your code write just second row is, your close code is in the For loop. If you write close code at the end of {} you will get right answer. :)

Comment: Hi Grafeen, thank you for your reply. As soon as I am back at the office I will try to do your recommendation.

Comment: Please try it and let me know.

Comment: I tried it yesterday and it did not work. For every run of the code, it does not write to the next row. Thanks for the follow-up.